# .NET Sniffer for all running applications

Tags: .net, packet-sniffers, winpcap, sniffer

Is there any way to capture all endpoint requesteds from all running applications in some desktop? Including web-based apps and client-server apps. I just want to capture the endpoints urls from those requests.

Regards.

Comment: Would Fiddler be of use?

Comment: I want to use inside of my console app in C#